# How do I load form fields based on a value changed in a DropdownList in my Asp.Net Core Razor App?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm building an Asp.Net Core Razor application.
I'm using DevExtreme controls in my Razor page.
My page contains a dropdown/SelectBox. On a value change from my SelectBox
I would like to fire an event server side which will preload some fields
on my page and preserve previously entered user fields.

Would I need to do an HttpPost to trigger this?

Or should I some how redirect to my controller index with a parameter?

**Here is a sample snippet of my Razor Page:**

```
<form method="post" action="SaveDocument">
    // To simplify I didn't include the DevExtreme form definition, here I'm just assuming I'm firing an event attached to a button.
    <button id="LoadButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="PreLoadFormDataBasedOnDropdown()">Preload Form Data</button>
    
    // This is the default save
    <button id="SaveButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="SaveDocument()">Save Form</button>
</form>

// This fires client side
function SaveDocument() {
    let documentData = GetDocumentData();
    $("#hCurrentDocumentData").val(documentData);
}
```

**Here is a sample snippet of my controller:**

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Guid? documentId, Guid? companyId)
    {
        // Load model data based on id
        if (documentId.HasValue)
        {
            // Retrieve document data and load the model
        }
        else if (companyId.HasValue)
        {
            // Get company data and load model
        }
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveDocument()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DocumentViewModel.CurrentDocument), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var requestString = ServerAddress + $"Documents/Save";
            var response = await client.PostAsync(requestString, content);
            var results = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var document = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(results);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { documentId = document.DocumentId });
        }
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PreLoadFormDataBasedOnDropdown(string companyName)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var requestString = ServerAddress + $"Company/GetCompanyByName{companyName}";
            var response = await client.GetAsync(requestString);
            var results = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var company = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(results);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { companyId = company.CompanyId });
        }
    }
}
```

I am relatively new to Razor and confused on how to proceed with this.
Is this a case where I should be using Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a case where I should be using Ajax?

Yes, Ajax is an excellent choice. But from your description, after the value changes(select/dropdownlist), you want to load/update the form fields, if that is the case, you could consider using JQuery Ajax to render the partial view.

For example

Here is a company model, we can create a partial view to display the company detailed information. In the Select tag (or DropDownList), we can show the company name, after user select the company name, we will use JQuery Ajax to call the partial view and display the company detailed information.

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } 
}
```

Contorller:

```
    private readonly IDataRepository _repository;
    public SampleController(IDataRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //get all company name and used to populate the select tag.
        ViewData["company"] = _repository.GetCompanies().Select(c=> new SelectListItem(){ Value=c.CompanyName, Text = c.CompanyName }).ToList();
        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PreLoadFormDataBasedOnDropdown(string companyName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName))
        {
            //find elements based on the company name
            var result =   _repository.FindCompanyByName(companyName);

            return PartialView("_PVDisplayCompany", result);
        }
        return Ok("Model invalid!");
    }
```

View page (Index.cshtml):

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
 
<form method="post" action="SaveDocument">

    <select id="selectcompany" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["company"])"> 
    </select>
     
    <button id="LoadButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" >Preload Form Data</button>
     
    <button id="SaveButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="SaveDocument()">Save Form</button>

    <div id="result">

    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#LoadButton").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Sample/PreLoadFormDataBasedOnDropdown",
                method: "Post",
                data: { companyName: $("#selectcompany").val() },
                success: function (res) {
                    //update the div content, and display the partial view 
                    $("#result").html(res);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(e.responseText);
                }

            })

        });
    });
</script>
}
```

[Note] Since the layout page has already added the JQuery reference, there is no need to add it again. If you didn't add the JQuery reference in the layout page or without using the layout page, you have to add the JQuery reference first. Reference: [ASP.Net Core: jQuery AJAX and JSON Example in ASP.Net Core MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-Example-in-ASPNet-Core-MVC.aspx)

Partial view ("_PVDisplayCompany.cshtml"):

```
@model WebApplication5.Models.Company

<h4>Company Detail</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="_PVDisplayCompany">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CompanyCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CompanyCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CompanyCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CompanyName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CompanyName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CompanyName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
 
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

You can change the JQuery script to use the select tag change event.

Besides, if you don't want to use the partial view, in the controller, after getting the data, you can return a json result, then, in the view page, you can find or create the html elements, and display the response data with them.